# What is the optimal width/height to use with pairs of android:layout_align*?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Let's say I have:

```xml
    <View
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/someOtherView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/someOtherView" />
```

To avoid errors (RuntimeException if not checking before), I need to specify `android:layout_height`.
What value is preferable? It will be overridden anyway, but there may be some performance issues like those that lead to the preference of `0dip`/`px` for `LinearLayout` children with weights.
So - `0dip`, `1px`, `fill_parent` (I defiantly believe this to be a more appropriate name than `match_parent`), or `wrap_content`?

Comment: I would put `0dip` as it clearly shows that the size is computed after, unlinke `wrap_content` or `match_parent` which can confuse someone looking at your code.

Comment: `fill_parent` is not the more appropriate name because it suggests that the view will take up the remaining space of the parent, which is not the actual behavior. The actual behavior is it gives the child the same width/height as the parent. That's why they added `match_parent`.

Comment: @Karakuri Now consider it in a RelativeLayout, with layout_below another view. Is it matching the parent view? No. Is it filling the remaining height? Yes. Sorry for the off-topic note.

Comment: RelativeLayout has special rules about how it arranges its children that can override the specifications for layout_width and layout_height. That doesn't mean `fill_parent` accurately reflects the meaning of that specification. Also, this is meant to describe how the views are measured, not necessarily how they are actually layed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell if you are proposing this as the functionally, aesthetically or algorithmically optimal solution, or pointing out is is **a** solution.

Comment: All of the above. This is pretty standard practice and doesn't require the views to resolve measure specifications like 'match_parent' or `wrap_content`.